# Yii2 - Is there a way to write basic characters in search model and results show all queries with both basic and special characters?

Tags: php, database, yii2

Just to say it first, I'm relatively new in Yii2, so thanks for understanding.

I am using MariaDB database engine.

For example, in queryParams i wrote 'bosiljcic' and since I don't have 'bosiljcic' in db, I get empty string as a response in API.
What I have in db is 'Bosiljčić'. How can I write a query to list all queries that are close in terms of being written down. Like 'bosiljcic' and 'bosiljčić' ?

My code so far:

```
    public function actionSearch()
{
    // get search params
    $term = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('term');

    $page = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('page') ?: 1;
    $pageSize = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('page-size') ?: 20;

    // query
    if ($term == null || strlen($term) < 3) {
        $authors = [];
    } else {
        $query = AuthorSummary::find();
        // $query->where(['like', 'name', $term]);
        // $query->where(['RLIKE', 'name', $term]);
        // $query->where(['REGEXP', 'name', 'PHP|MYSQL']);
        $query->andWhere(['published' => Author::STATUS_PUBLISHED]);
        $query->orderBy('name');
        // pagination
        $query->limit($pageSize);
        $query->offset(($page - 1) * $pageSize);

        $authors = $query->all();
    }

    return ['authors' => $authors];
}
```

Comment: Depending of the database engine you are using there may be some solutions already available there for you (it's more of a database question than Yii question). Check `levenshtein distance` or similar.

Comment: @Bizley `levenshtein distance` is not a good solution for this. That's because the string can have multiple special characters resulting into big distance between the string with special characters and without them. Meanwhile strings that are similar can have small distance between them even if they are not related.

Comment: @MichalHynčica yes, maybe you are right, I'm not expert at this.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but workaround. Store in your table separate name field with basic characters only. You can get it with:
`iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);`

Do the same with your search phrase.
Search both, original phrase in original field and transliterated phrase in transliterated field.

You can also try with  SOUNDEX or SOUNDS LIKE function, but those works with english letters only AFAIK.